# Convert Byte Array (from legacy program data file) to Powershell object

Tags: powershell

I have a "structured" file (logical fixed-length records) from a legacy program on a legacy (non-MS) operating system. I know how the records were structured in the original program, but the original O/S handled structured data as a sequence of bytes for file I/O, so a hex dump won't show you anything more than what the record length is (there are marker bytes and other record overhead imposed by the access method API used to generate the file originally).

Once I have the sequence of bytes in a Powershell variable, with the overhead bytes "cut away", how can I convert this into a structured object? Some of the "fields" are 16-bit integers, some are strings of the form [s]data (where [s] is a byte giving the length of the "real" data in that field), some are BCD coded fixed-point numbers, some are IEEE floats.

(I haven't been specific about the structure, either on the Powershell side or on the legacy side, because I am seeking a more-or-less 'generic' solution/technique, as I actually have several different files with different record structures to process.)

Comment: wow this is an interesting one, can you tell us a little bit more about the input data?  specifically how did the original OS determine the data type of a record?  Presumably, you can just create an interpreter that essentially follows the same rules the legacy OS would to parse the data, so you go through the string, find the first marker byte, read in data till "end of record" marker byte and then parse the data based on the rules for that data type, most likely making use of `[convert]` to convert from binary to usable text.

Comment: The original OS didn't determine the type of the record; it was the application that did, and when it passed a system-pointer to the record as the pointer to the data buffer for the write-record API call, the API call would simply treat it as raw bytes in memory, wrap it with the record overhead, and write it to the file. If the original application was written in Pascal, there would have been a `TYPE something = RECORD`... declaration in the program's source code.

Comment: What was the legacy OS and the app? Maybe there already exists an implementation that can be ported to .Net / Powershell with some effort.

Comment: ok, so how would the original program determine the data types at read time? better yet can you tell us what OS and app were talking about so we can do some outside research

Comment: For what it's worth, if there turns out to be a good generic way of handling this, such that I don't need to manually parse the incoming data (even though I know the structure _in this case_), I just might be able to turn it into a shareable Powershell module for handling "record-based" files.

Comment: For those who've asked, the original app was a custom in-house app, the original OS was called CTOS (from a company called Convergent), and the program didn't determine the data type from the file; it "knew" what the data structure was because it had defined it programmatically. For those who just happen to be familiar with the OS, the portion of the API used was what Convergent called "Direct Access Method".

Comment: Thanks for the OS info, so it sounds like the only thing you have to go on is the marker bytes for beginning and end of a record and a bunch of data in between right?  do you know if any records were fixed length?  if not I'm just not sure how you would be able to determine what sort of data is in a field, which you'll need in order to do a convert on it.. once you work out what kind of data is encoded in the record the rest is easy but I'm not sure how you'd get there

Comment: The records in this case were all fixed length. I can strip out the overhead; I know how the overhead was created and added to the records in the file.

Comment: Knowing the field structure isn't the issue; the idea is that I have a structured PowerShell object in my script, and I want to more-or-less "coerce" the array of bytes into the psobject. In Pascal, I might do this with a variant record, in C I might do it with a union; in either case, I'd just assign the array-of-bytes to a bytearray field in the structure, and then read the structured object from the rest of the structure.  That technique won't work in Powershell; I'm hoping to find a technique that will, that doesn't involve requiring me to "manually" parse and convert the bytearray.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I tried to do it by creating a type that could take the buffer and overwrite a struct so that all the fields were nicely filled in. However, certain issues arose (regarding struct layout, fixed buffers and mixing fixed and managed members) and I also realised that there was no guarantee that the data in the buffer would be properly (or even legally) aligned. Decided to try a more programmatic path.

"Manual" parsing is out, so how about automatic parsing? You're going to need to define the members of your `PSobject` at some point, why not do it in a way that can help programmatically parse the data. This method does not require the data in the buffer to be correctly aligned or even contiguous. You can also have fields overlap to separate raw unions into the individual members (though, typically, only one will contain a "correct" value).

First step, build a hash table to identify the members, the offset in the buffer, their data types and, if an array, the number of elements :

```
$struct = @{
 field1 = 0,[int],0;  # 0 means not an array
 field2 = 4,[byte],16; # a C string maybe
 field3 = 24,[char],32;  # wchar_t[32] ? note: skipped over bytes 20-23
 field4 = 56,[double],0
}
# the names field1/2/3/4 are arbitrary, any valid member name may be used (but not
# necessarily any valid hash key if you want a PSObject as the end result).
# also, the values could be hash tables instead of arrays. that would allow
# descriptive names for the values but doesn't affect the end result.
```

Next, use `[BitConverter]` to extract the required data. The problem here is that we need to call the correct method for all the varying types. Just use a (big) `switch` statement. The basic principle is the same for most values, get the type indicator and initial offset from the `$struct` definition then call the correct `[BitConverter]` method and supply the buffer and initial offset, update the offset to where the next element of an array would be and then repeat for as many array elements as are required. The only trap here is that the data in the buffer must have the same format as expected by `[BitConverter]`, so for the `[double]` example, the bytes in the buffer must conform to IEEE-754 floating point format (assuming that `[BitConverter]::ToDouble()` is used). Thus, for example, raw data from a Paradox database will need some tweeking because it flips the high bit to simplify sorting.

```
$struct.keys | foreach {
# key order is undefined but that won't affect the final object's members
   $hashobject = @{}
} {
   $fieldoffs = $struct[$_][0]
   $fieldtype = $struct[$_][1]
   if (($arraysize = $struct[$_][2]) -ne 0) { # yes, I'm a C programmer from way back
      $array = @()
   } else {
      $array = $null
   }
:w while ($arraysize-- -ge 0) {
      switch($fieldtype) {
         ([int]) {
            $value = [bitconverter]::toint32($buffer, $fieldoffs)
            $fieldoffs += 4
         }
         ([byte]) {
            $value = $buffer[$fieldoffs++]
         }
         ([char]) {
            $value = [bitconverter]::tochar($buffer, $fieldoffs)
            $fieldoffs += 2
         }
         ([string]) { # ANSI string, 1 byte per character
            $array = new-object string (,[char[]]$buffer[$fieldoffs..($fieldoffs+$arraysize)])
# $arraysize has already been decremented so don't need to subtract 1
            break w # "array size" was actually string length so don't loop
#
# description:
# first, get a slice of the buffer as a byte[] (assume single byte characters)
# next, convert each byte to a char in a char[]
# then, invoke the constructor String(Char[])
# finally, put the String into $array ready for insertion into $hashobject
#
# Note the convoluted syntax - New-Object expects the second argument to be
# an array of the constructor parameters but String(Char[]) requires only
# one argument that is itself an array. By itself,
#    [char[]]$buffer[$fieldoffs..($fieldoffs+$arraysize)]
# is treated by PowerShell as an argument list of individual chars, corrupting the
# constructor call. The normal trick is to prepend a single comma to create an array
# of one element which is itself an array
#    ,[char[]]$buffer[$fieldoffs..($fieldoffs+$arraysize)]
# but this won't work because of the way PowerShell parses the command line. The
# space before the comma is ignored so that instead of getting 2 arguments (a string
# "String" and the array of an array of char), there is only one argument, an array
# of 2 elements ("String" and array of array of char) thereby totally confusing
# New-Object. To make it work you need to ALSO isolate the single element array into
# its own expression. Hence the parentheses
#    (,[char[]]$buffer[$fieldoffs..($fieldoffs+$arraysize)])
#
         }
      }
      if ($null -ne $array) {
# must be in this order* to stop the -ne from enumerating $array to compare against
# $null. this would result in the condition being considered false if $array were
# empty ( (@() -ne $null) -> $null -> $false ) or contained only one element with
# the value 0 ( (@(0) -ne $null) -> (scalar) 0 -> $false ).
         $array += $value
# $array is not $null so must be an array to which $value is appended
      } else {
# $array is $null only if $arraysize -eq 0 before the loop (and is now -1)
         $array = $value
# so the loop won't repeat thus leaving this one scalar in $array
      }
   }
   $hashobject[$_] = $array
}

#*could have reversed it as
#   if ($array -eq $null) { scalar } else { collect array }
# since the condition will only be true if $array is actually $null or contains at
# least 2 $null elements (but no valid conversion will produce $null)
```

At this point there is a hash table, `$hashobject`, with keys equal to the field names and values containing the bytes from the buffer arranged into single (or arrays of) numeric (inc. char/boolean) values or (ANSI) strings. To create a (proper) object, just invoke `New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $hashobject` or use `[PSCustomObject]$hashobject`.

Of course, if the buffer actually contained structured data then the process would be more complicated but the basic procedure would be the same. Note also that the "types" used in the `$struct` hash table have no direct effect on the resultant types of the object members, they are only convenient selectors for the `switch` statement. It would work just as well with strings or numbers. In fact, the parentheses around the case labels are because `switch` parses them the same as command arguments. Without the parentheses, the labels would be treated as literal strings. With them, the labels are evaluated as a type object. Both the label and the switch value are then converted to strings (that's what switch does for values other than script blocks or `$null`) but each type has a distinct string representation so the case labels will still match up correctly. (Not really on point but still interesting, I think.)

Several optimisations are possible but increase the complexity slightly. E.g.

```
         ([byte]) { # already have a byte[] so why collect bytes one at a time
            if ($arraysize -ge 0) { # was originally -gt 0 so want a byte[]
               $array = [byte[]]$buffer[$fieldoffs..($fieldoffs+$arraysize)]
# slicing the byte array produces an object array (of bytes) so cast it back
            } else { # $arraysize was 0 so just a single byte
               $array = $buffer[$fieldoffs]
            }
            break w # $array ready for insertion into $hashobject, don't need to loop
         }
```

But what if my strings are actually Unicode?, you say. Easy, just use existing methods from the `[Text.Encoding]` class,

```
         [string] { # Unicode string, 2 (LE) bytes per character
            $array = [text.encoding]::unicode.getstring([byte[]]$buffer[$fieldoffs..($fieldoffs+$arraysize*2+1)])
# $arraysize should be the string length so, initially, $arraysize*2 is the byte
# count and $arraysize*2-1 is the end index (relative to $fieldoffs) but $arraysize
# was decremented so the end index is now $arraysize*2+1, i.e. length*2-1 = (length-1)*2+1
            break w # got $array, no loop
         }
```

You could also have both ANSI and Unicode by utilising a different type indicator for the ANSI string, maybe `[char[]]`. Remember, the type indicators do not affect the result, they just have to be distinct (and hopefully meaningful) identifiers.

I realise that this is not quite the "just dump the bytes into a union or variant record" solution mentioned in the OPs comment but PowerShell is based in .NET and uses managed objects where this sort of thing is largely prohibited (or difficult to get working, as I found). For example, assuming you could just dump raw chars (not bytes) into a `String`, how would the `Length` property get updated? This method also allows some useful preprocessing such as splitting up unions as noted above or converting raw `byte` or `char` arrays into the `String`s they represent.